# Filtering Swagger endpoints with IDocumentFilter and UserPrincipal Claims for authorisation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui

I am trying to filter swagger endpoints with the IDocumentFilter, based on a users Claims based on JWT tokens.
When my implementation of IDocumentFilter is called, the users claims of the HttpContext are always empty, however, if I call any endpoints, the users Claims are available.

startup code

```
public static async void Launch(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    builder.Services.AddControllers()
    builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();


    string[] swaggerEndpoints = new string[]
    {
        "Test", "test",
    };


    builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(o =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < swaggerEndpoints.Length; i += 2)
        {
            o.SwaggerDoc(swaggerEndpoints[i], new OpenApiInfo()
            {
                Version = "v1",
                Title = swaggerEndpoints[i],
                Description = swaggerEndpoints[i + 1]
            });
        }
        o.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
        {
            Name = "Authorization",
            Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
            Scheme = "Bearer",
            BearerFormat = "JWT",
            In = ParameterLocation.Header,
            Description = "JSON Web Token based security",
        });
        o.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement()
        {
            {
                new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Reference = new OpenApiReference
                    {
                        Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                        Id = "Bearer"
                    }
                },
                new string[] {}
            }
        });
        o.DocumentFilter<CheckAuthedUserFilter>();
    });
    builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();



    // Add JWT configuration
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(o =>
    {
        o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        o.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        o.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    }).AddJwtBearer(o =>
    {
        o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"])),
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ClockSkew = System.TimeSpan.Zero
        };
    });


    builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
    builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

    //security certificates
    if (File.Exists(builder.Configuration["SSL:certLocation"]))
    {
        builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
        {
            var appServices = serverOptions.ApplicationServices;
            serverOptions.ListenAnyIP(8080, portOptions =>
            {
                portOptions.UseHttps(builder.Configuration["SSL:certLocation"], builder.Configuration["SSL:certPassword"], h =>
                {
                });
            });
        });
    }
    app = builder.Build();
    
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseCors("CorsList");
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });

    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < swaggerEndpoints.Length; i += 2)
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/{swaggerEndpoints[i]}/swagger.json", swaggerEndpoints[i]);
        }
        c.ConfigObject.AdditionalItems.Add("persistAuthorization", true);
        c.DefaultModelExpandDepth(-1);
    });

    app.Start();
}
```

IDocumentFilter implementation

```
    public class CheckAuthedUserFilter : IDocumentFilter
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;

        public AddAuthHeaderOperationFilter(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

        public void Apply(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
        {
            //httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Claims is always empty and the identity is not authenticated
            foreach (var claim in httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Claims)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(claim.Type + " " + claim.Value);
            }
        }
    }
```

From my research on this problem, it seems that my IDocumentFilter is being called before the Authorisation/Authentication is completed, and many suggestions are too have the `app.UseAuthentication()`, `app.useAuthoirization()` and `app.UseRouting()` before `app.UseSwagger()` and `app.UseSwaggerUI(...)` however, this does not seem to help in this siutation.

Comment: What you mean "however, this does not seem to help in this siutation." do you mean you still couldn't get the user claim inside the CheckAuthedUserFilter ?

Comment: Yes, the user Claims were not available in the HttpContext, even with the suggestions.